# jquery image carousel doesn't work after two clicks

Tags: jquery, image, carousel

I'm trying to make a simple jquery image carousel.

Here's my complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/6fwbS/19/

The following function gets called when you click the "increase" button to slide the images to the left and make one disappear. The problem that I'm experiencing is that it only seems to work once. The first time you click it loads the next image into the container. The second time you click it calls that alert twice. I don't know why it is calling the alert twice on the second click. The third time you click it it does not alert at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated. For an example of the end goal click on decrease after you run it. What I'm ultimately trying to do here is get a new image into the container when each button is clicked and cycle back and forth through the images.

```
function slide_img_left() {

    var imgs = imgArr.length;

    a++;
    if (a >= imgs) {
        a = 0;
    }

    b = a - 1;
    c = a + 1;

    if (b < 0) {
        b = imgs - 1;
    }
    if (c >= imgs) {
        c = 0;
    }

    $('.left_slot').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        left: '-=50px'
    }, 300, function() {
        $('.left_slot').remove();
    });

    $('.middle_slot').animate({
        left: '-=50px'
    }, 300, function() {
        $('.middle_slot').attr('class', 'left_slot');
        $('.right_slot').attr('class', 'middle_slot');
        alert(c);

    });

    $('.right_slot').animate({
        left: '-=50px'
    }, 300);

    $("#basic_div").append(imgArr[c][0]);
        $("#varsDiv").html(" var b = " + b + " var a = " + a + " var c = " + c);

}
```

Comment: why re-inventing the wheel? there are a lot of jQuery carousel plugins out there. and i mean a lot.

Comment: I need to incorporate a lot of tricky php later in the process and also I just kinda want to learn how to do jquery. The best way for me to learn is to experiment and do it. Plus this way I can more easily customize it to meet my exact needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('.left_slot')` in your *complete* callback may refer to the new left slot that was created by one of the other *complete* callbacks.

This is the relevant part of `slide_img_left()` fixed so that it alerts only once:

```
var left = $('.left_slot');
var middle = $('.middle_slot');
var right = $('.right_slot');

left.animate({
    opacity: 0,
    left: '-=50px'
}, 300, function() {
    left.remove();
});


middle.animate({
    left: '-=50px'
}, 300, function() {
    middle.attr('class', 'left_slot');
    right.attr('class', 'middle_slot');
    alert(c);

});

right.animate({
    left: '-=50px'
}, 300);
```

Link to updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FMqz/) (**Edit:** updated the link to point to a forked version.)

Comment: Thanks! That was a ton of help!